# How do I emulate 'Notes' from Apple and start the app with a navigation controller with a 'back' view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application that has a login page.  It then moves to a navigation controller that has a collection view as its root view controller.    When the app starts and there is only one item in the collection, I want to have the navigation controller automatically push to that item and allow the user to use 'back' to view the collection.  This is the same behavior that is in 'Notes' from Apple.

The idea is to allow the user to immediately start to use the app and only 'discover' the need for the collection view after using the app for some time.

I am using IB, storyboards, and segues for my view transitions.

If I programmatically have the root view controller do a performSegue in its viewWillLoad: I get an error about causing a transition while a transition is still in process.

If I move the code calling performSegue into the didLoad, then the user sees a double transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found that the following worked the best for me.

```
if (/* reason to change back list*/) {
    UIViewController * rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"backViewController"];
    NSArray * viewControllers = @[rootViewController, self];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
}
```

setViewControllers seems to be the best way to manipulate the stack.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation controller usually manages the underlying stack itself. That is, you pass it an initial view controller, and then through segues or `pushViewController:animated:` the stack is altered. However, there is nothing stopping you from manually altering the stack. In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, you can check the number of items, and if it's 1, do something like this:

```
UIViewController *singleItemViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleItem"];

NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [sender.destinationViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[viewControllers addObject:singleItemViewController];
sender.destinationViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Now instead of starting at the first view controller of the stack, you start at the second one, with a back button to navigate back.